# spark Image - actual image location

Tags: flash, apache-flex, image

Quick question ..

I have a spark image control with scaleMode = 'letterbox'. When I load an image smaller than the actual control it centers nicely.  Now what I need to know is the ACTUAL location of the image within the letterbox.  In other words, if it is padded 100px on each side, I need to know the amount of padding, if any.

Anyone have any ideas?

-JD

Comment: I am not using the spark image control (i'm guessing it is a part of the new Flex SDK Hero), but doesn't the image-control have a contentWidth/Height-property you could use to compare it to the actual width/height of your component?

Comment: You could take a look at the as file in the framework for the spark component and try to get the loaded image. Then you may have access to its position. The risk is that the property containing the image may be private.

Answer (score 0):

Try extending the Spark Image component to include some helpful read-only properties for accessing the scaled image location (and dimensions).

The following will create 4 new bindable properties to return the actual scaled x, y, width and height of the image displayed inside the Spark Image component.

```
package 
{
    import spark.components.Image;

    public class ExtendedSparkImage extends Image
    {

        public function ExtendedSparkImage()
        {
            super();
        }

        /**
         * Returns the X coordinate offset of the image display taking into account 
         * the actual constraints of the container.  If no scaling has occurred it 
         * will return zero.
         */ 
        [Bindable(event="scaledXOffsetChanged")]
        public function get scaledXOffset():Number
        {
            var num:Number = 0;

            if (scaleMode == "letterbox")
            {
                try
                {                   
                    if ( (width > 0) && (sourceWidth < sourceHeight) )
                    {       
                        num = (width - scaledWidth) / 2;    
                    }                   
                }
                catch(e:Error)
                {
                    num = 0;
                }
            }

            return num;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the Y coordinate offset of the image display taking into account 
         * the actual constraints of the container.  If no scaling has occurred it 
         * will return zero.
         */ 
        [Bindable(event="scaledYOffsetChanged")]
        public function get scaledYOffset():Number
        {
            var num:Number = 0;

            if (scaleMode == "letterbox")
            {
                try
                {                   
                    if ((height > 0) && (sourceHeight < sourceWidth))
                    {
                        num = (height - scaledHeight) / 2;              
                    }                   
                }
                catch(e:Error)
                {
                    num = 0;
                }
            }

            return num;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the width of the image display taking into account the actual 
         * constraints of the container.  If no scaling has occurred the actual
         * width of the control is returned.
         */ 
        [Bindable(event="scaledWidthChanged")]
        public function get scaledWidth():Number
        {
            var num:Number = this.width;

            if (scaleMode == "letterbox")
            {
                try
                {
                    if ( (width > 0) && (sourceWidth < sourceHeight) )
                    {
                        num = (sourceWidth/sourceHeight) * width;                       
                    }                   
                }
                catch(e:Error)
                {
                    num = this.width;
                }
            }



            return num;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the height of the image display taking into account the actual 
         * constraints of the container.  If no scaling has occurred the actual
         * height of the control is returned.
         */ 
        [Bindable(event="scaledHeightChanged")]
        public function get scaledHeight():Number
        {
            var num:Number = this.width;

            if (scaleMode == "letterbox")
            {
                try
                {
                    if ((height > 0) && (sourceHeight < sourceWidth))
                    {
                        num = (sourceHeight/sourceWidth) * height;
                    }                   
                }
                catch(e:Error)
                {
                    num = this.height;
                }
            }

            return num;
        }
    }
}
```